# Как в функции strpos убрать регистрозависимость?

Tags: php

Есть функция поиска слова в строке

```
$text = "СЛОВО";

if (strpos($text, 'слово') !== false) // именно через жесткое сравнение
{
    echo 'Найдено';
} else {
    echo 'Не найдено';
}
```

Если в строке слово с большой буквы, то функция покажет "Не найдено", как это исправить?
Т.е. нужно убрать зависимость от регистра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В нижний регистр приведите слово сначала:

```
$text = "СЛОВО";

if (strpos(strtolower($text), 'слово') !== false) 
{
    echo 'Найдено';
} else {
    echo 'Не найдено';
}
```

Или используйте [`stripos`](http://php.net/stripos). Он не чувствителен к регистру.

Answer (score 3):

На будущее. Набираем в адресной строке своего браузера два слова, [strpos регистронезависимый](https://www.google.com/search?q=strpos+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9). И первая же ссылка дает ответ. **Это гораздо быстрее, чем писать свой вопрос на Stack Overflow.**

Только читать надо найденную статью внимательно, и из неё перейти по ссылке уже на ту функцию, которая нам на самом деле нужна в 2019 году - **mb_stripos()**

Comment: Какая дальнейшая судьба таких вопросов на SO? Удаление через год или вечное хранение в анналах истории?

Comment: Автоматом удалятся вопросы без ответов. Мне кажется можно проголосовать за удаление данного вопроса.

Comment: @u_mulder вопрос не по правилам?